# Using alice fixtures function to calculate values

Tags: php, nelmio-alice, alice-fixtures

I'm using alice fixtures https://github.com/nelmio/alice and I'm curious whether it's possible to for example multiply `<current()>`. Let's have this code:

```
entity{1..5}:
    value: <current()> * 100
```

You get the idea. It would create 5 entities first with value 100, second value 200 etc. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible, and not likely to be added natively to the bundle!

However, it's not a stretch to create a [custom provider](https://github.com/nelmio/alice/blob/2.x/doc/customizing-data-generation.md#custom-faker-data-providers), as per the suggestion of [theofidry](https://github.com/theofidry), a contributor to the bundle.

> **theofidry:**
>
> The problem with what you would like to do is that the string `<current()> * @offer_price_<current()>`value must, besides being parsed and the value resolved, be evaluated. That's not something that will be added. If you want to do this kind of thing, you should add a custom provider:
>
> ```
> total_item_price_{1..4}:
>    value: <calculateItemValue(<current()>, @offer_price_<current()>)>
> ```

Source: https://github.com/nelmio/alice/issues/295#issuecomment-217748524

Comment: As I checked, nested functions work in version 3 that is in beta now so I'll have to find another workaround. Using custom provider didn't come up to my mind so I'll build some kind of solution using that. Thanks!